# How to select all parameter values in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I have a parameters @Year and @Month in my report, where month has assigned values like January(label): 1(values), February: 2, ...
My datased is feeded by stored procedure which has a filter
[image]

```
WHERE (cal.CalendarYear = @Year) AND (cal.MonthId = @Month)
```

When I check 'Allow multiply values' in parameter settings, it returns an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar into int.

How can I select all values (by default)?

Comment: Your procedure is not designed to accept multiple values. You should rewrite it or redesigned your report not to use this procedure but the code

Comment: @sepupic How can it be achieved?

Comment: `@Year` and `@Month` are both type of int? If you want to make them accepting multiple values, they need to be varchar and then you need to split them and change `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Rokuto Do I need to write own split function?

Comment: @StanislavJirák I think there are plenty examples of split function, but yes, you need one.
Edit:
I forgot. SQL Server 2016 has his own split function [STRING_SPLIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql).

Comment: Yes, if you can rewrite your sp, you should make parameters of varchar type and pass in strings (reporting do it, as comma separated list). Then you use a split function inside your procedure

Comment: OK, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use a Stored Proc you can easily solve the problem.

Copy the SQL from your stored proc (excluding the PROC definition, just the main code) and paste it in as your dataset query.

Change your `= @Year` and `= @Month` to `IN(@Year)` and `IN(@Month)`

That's all there is to it, no joining, splitting or anything else.

SSRS will inject the parameter values as comma separated values correctly for you.

Answer (score 0):

When you select multiple values, you pass the parameter to the procedure as an expression with Join().

[image]

Then in your procedure change your month parameter to be of type nvarchar(max).

Create a temp table and use a t-sql split string function (Google this, there are so many varieties but if you're stuck we can find one) to split the string into a table.  Then inner join to your table in your procedure to filter on the selections.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message about "nvarchar into int" suggests a data type mismatch between your SSRS parameter and your `MonthId` column. Check the Report Parameter Properties -> General -> Data type for the former and your table schema for the latter, and make sure they're either both text/varchar or both integers.

Allowing your query to handle multiple parameter values should be much simpler than needing to use joins and splits. Just use `IN` instead of `=`, and put your parameter name inside a set of brackets.

```
AND (cal.MonthId IN (@Month))
```

To set the defaults for your parameter, go to the Report Parameter Properties -> Default Values. Select the `Specify values` option, and add your numbers 1-12 as separate Value records.