# How to pass multiply values parameter to a procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I want to pass multiply values parameter to my procedure and use it as a filter. My parameter is called @Month and it's datatype is NVARCHAR(MAX) in the procedure.
I have used filter as

```
WHERE (cal.CalendarYear = @Year) AND (cal.MonthId IN (@Month))
```

and also tried STRING_SPLIT function.
However, when I run my report, it return an error
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12' to data type int.
[image]

Comment: Use a `TABLE` variable to pass the values as rows instead.

Comment: See my Answer on your previous related question. It may save you a lot of work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45012713/how-to-select-all-parameter-values-in-ssrs/45021542#45021542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot give a varchar string with comma separated values, and expect the query to process it as a 'in' list.
The way that would work is when you would concatenate your sql statement in the stored procedure, and then execute the sql string with sp_executesql.
Using string_split is one way of doing it, but you have to be aware that it gives you a table with varchars, not integers.
For completeness I should mention that the most 'robust' way of doing this is passing a table type variable to your stored procedure, as described here: [How to pass table value parameters to stored procedure from .net code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595353/how-to-pass-table-value-parameters-to-stored-procedure-from-net-code).
With the split_string, you could try something like this:

```
select
 -- your fields
from
    manytables mt
    join string_split(@Month,',') months on cast(months.value as int) = cal.monthId
where 
    cal.Calenderyear = @year
```